# Bootstrap Modal - Simple password protected button

Tags: javascript, php, password-protection

I have a page with a modal. Inside the modal , i have two buttons. `Close` and `Save Changes`. I am trying to add a simple password protected on `Save Changes` button press. User press button and a pop up with only password. If password is correct continue the rest code. Else alert message.

js:

```
$('#UpdateForm').submit(function(event) {
    if ($pass=="pass") {
        echo "Rest Code Here";
    } else {
        echo "Wrong!";
    }
}
```

I think the code would like like this. How to add pop up and make it work. It is simple protected and no secure as is for local use.

Comment: Why use a password if security is not important? You could simply ask "Do you really want to save this?". The reason I say this is because you have implemented the password check in Javascript, in other words, in public code, which anybody could easily change.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I am afraid that user will press save. Password is better. It is local app, simple use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Window prompt() Method`.
The prompt() method displays a dialog box that prompts the visitor for input.

A prompt box is often used if you want the user to input a value before entering a page.

Note: When a prompt box pops up, the user will have to click either "OK" or "Cancel" to proceed after entering an input value. Do not overuse this method, as it prevents the user from accessing other parts of the page until the box is closed.

[w3schools.com - Window prompt() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp)

You can try the following code:

```
$('#UpdateForm').submit(function(event) {
    y = prompt("Please insert code to continue.");
    if (y == "pass") {
        alert("Rest Code Here");
    } else {
        alert("Wrong!");
        //Stop closing modal
        return false;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) to do it

See here https://codepen.io/5hiny/pen/PobNbGQ

```
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Enter password to save',
  input: 'text',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonText: 'Submit',
  showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
  preConfirm: (pass) => {
    if (pass == 'password') {
      document.write("SAVE");
    } else {
      document.write("FAIL");
    }
  },
  allowOutsideClick: () => !Swal.isLoading()
})
```